# Passing variable to controller through Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

```
Rail 5.2
datatables
```

In my views/books/index.html.slim, I am loading a partial, from another MVC, as follows:

```
 = render  partial: 'authors/index', :locals => {:author => @book.author}
```

In my views/authors/_index.html, I have the following:

```
.....    
table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.nowrap#AuthorsIndex.display
.....

javascript:
  $('#AuthorsIndex').DataTable({
    ajax: '/authors',
    columns: [
      {title: 'Publish Date', data: 'created_at'},
      {title: 'Publisher', data: 'publisher'},
      {title: 'Title', data: 'title'},
    ]
  });
```

And, in my controllers/authors_controllers.rb, I have the following:

```
def index
  @authors = Author.where(author: "John Doe")
  render json: { data: @authors }
end
```

When I run it, the authors table displays properly. The problem, is that the author name is hard coded in the controller action. My _index partial, is receiving the author name, but how do I get it to the authors controller, as part of the Ajax call I am making? New to Ajax/Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```rb
#_index.html
javascript:
  $('#AuthorsIndex').DataTable({
    ajax: '/authors?author=<%= author %>',
    columns: [
      {title: 'Publish Date', data: 'created_at'},
      {title: 'Publisher', data: 'publisher'},
      {title: 'Title', data: 'title'},
    ]
  });

#authors_controllers.rb
def index
  @authors = Author.where(author: params[:author])
  render json: { data: @authors }
end
```

Comment: Note that inserting it like this can cause problems. JavaScript should be escaped with the [`j`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j) helper, otherwise an author that includes the `'` character corrupts your JavaScript. Furthermore, since you are inserting the value directly into the URL, you should also [encode special URL characters](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form_component). Thus resulting in something like `<%= j URI.encode_www_form_component(author) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the necessary tools installed to test this, but the jQuery DataTable documentations says that you can provided custom data through the [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option.

> The [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option provides the ability to add additional data to
>   the request, or to modify the data object being submitted if required.
>
> ...
>
> As an object, the [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option is used to extend the data
>   object that DataTables constructs internally to submit to the server.
>   This provides an easy method of adding additional, static, parameters
>   to the data to be sent to the server. For dynamically calculated
>   values, use [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) as a function (see below).

The documentation also provides example scenarios, and goes further into detail about what can be provided.

```js
$('#AuthorsIndex').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '/authors',
    data: {author: '<%= j author %>'}
  },
  columns: [
    {title: 'Publish Date', data: 'created_at'},
    {title: 'Publisher',    data: 'publisher'},
    {title: 'Title',        data: 'title'}
  ]
});
```

Then in the controller:

```
def index
  @authors = Author.where(author: params[:author])
  render json: { data: @authors }
end
```

Comment: In most cases you want the front-end to conform to the back-end, not the other way around. Your current `index` action returns JSON, with a `data` attribute specifically for `DataTable` usage. You could simply `render json: @authors` if you add the option `ajax: { /* ... */ dataSrc: '' }` which says to uses the root of the response as data instead of using the default `data` attribute as data. See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc